# Does Eclipse allow stop tomcat at once?

Tags: linux, eclipse, tomcat, stoppropagation

I debugging application with Eclipse and Tomcat.
When I have made changes and would like stop tomcat to re-deploy.
But each time I must wait when tomcat write out in output, 2 times try to restart, stop on errors, etc.
Does it possible to stop tomcat immediately like kill 9 in Linux?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to your Debug View. There is usually a Debug Window where you can *Right-Click* and *Terminate and Disconnect All* processes run by eclipse.

See: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-terminateall.htm

Answer (score 1):

For our application, it helped to ensure that all running threads are killed at shutdown.